# WAR packaging error: encoded string too long

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I use grails 2.3.6 and get the following error while performing

```
grails dev war
```

Error:

```
|Compiling 84 GSP files for package [test]
.Error 
|
WAR packaging error: encoded string too long: 79912 bytes
```

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Do you have any large static files or GSP files with huge static blocks? If so I can make a recommendation as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the limit is 64k per block of static content (because DataOutputStream.writeUTF has that limit). You can workaround the limit by splitting up your GSP by adding any GSP "token" (for example: `<%-- some comment --%>`) in the static content to split it in max 64kB blocks.